# Multiple annotations not showing in Iphone mapview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, mkmapview

I have looked at other questions in stackoverflow that are closely related to my question however my issue is a bit different. Here, the code works fine on iPad but not my iPhone. My iPad will load all 300+ annotations correctly but my iPhone will only load only 80 of them. I'm not sure if this is due to the amount of memory on the iPhone because it does the same thing when I test on the simulator. Below you will find my sample code.

```
@interface MOVmapViewController ()

@end

#define VA_LATITUDE 37.413754;
#define VA_LONGITUDE -79.142246;

//Span
#define THE_SPAN 5.50f;



@implementation MOVmapViewController
@synthesize myMapView;

-(IBAction)findmylocation:(id)sender {

    myMapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    myMapView.delegate = MKMapTypeStandard;
    [myMapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES];

}

-(IBAction)setmaptype:(id)sender {

    switch (((UISegmentedControl *)sender).selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            myMapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
            break;
        case 1:
            myMapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
            break;
        case 2:
            myMapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
            break;

        default:
            myMapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
            break;

    }

}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typiclly from a nib.

    //Create the region
    MKCoordinateRegion myRegion;

    //Center
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
    center.latitude = VA_LATITUDE;
    center.longitude = VA_LONGITUDE;

    //Span
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = THE_SPAN;
    span.longitudeDelta = THE_SPAN;

    myRegion.center = center;
    myRegion.span = span;


    //Set our mapView
    [myMapView setRegion:myRegion animated:YES];

    //Annotations
    //Abingdon Lodge No. 48
    NSString *abingdon = @"325 W Main Street Abingdon, Virginia 24210";
    CLGeocoder *abingdongeo = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [abingdongeo geocodeAddressString:abingdon completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
        if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0) {CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
            MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:topResult];
            MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
            point.coordinate = placemark.coordinate;
            point.title = @"Abingdon Lodge No. 48";
            point.subtitle = @"Abingdon, VA";
            [self.myMapView addAnnotation:point]; }}];


    //York Lodge No. 12
    NSString *york = @"14411 Black Hollow Road Abingdon, Virginia 24210";
    CLGeocoder *yorkgeo = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [yorkgeo geocodeAddressString:york completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
        if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0) {CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
            MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:topResult];
            MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
            point.coordinate = placemark.coordinate;
            point.title = @"York Lodge No. 12";
            point.subtitle = @"Abingdon, VA";
            [self.myMapView addAnnotation:point]; }}];

    //Alberene Lodge No. 277
    NSString *alberene = @"2722 Plank Road Alberene, Virginia 22959";
    CLGeocoder *alberenegeo = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [alberenegeo geocodeAddressString:alberene completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
        if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0) {CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
            MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:topResult];
            MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
            point.coordinate = placemark.coordinate;
            point.title = @"Alberene Lodge No. 277";
            point.subtitle = @"Alberene, VA";
            [self.myMapView addAnnotation:point]; }}];


    //A. Douglas Smith, Jr. Lodge of Research No. 1949
    NSString *douglas = @"101 Callahan Drive Alexandria, Virginia 22301";
    CLGeocoder *douglasgeo = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [douglasgeo geocodeAddressString:douglas completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
        if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0) {CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
            MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:topResult];
            MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
            point.coordinate = placemark.coordinate;
            point.title = @"A. Douglas Smith, Jr. Lodge of Research No. 1949";
            point.subtitle = @"Alexandria, VA";
            [self.myMapView addAnnotation:point]; }}];

    //Alexandria-Washington Lodge No. 22 same location as above use lat/long
    CLLocationCoordinate2D washington;
    washington.latitude = 38.806758;
    washington.longitude = -77.065251;
    Annotation *alexandriawashingtonlodge = [Annotation alloc];
    alexandriawashingtonlodge.coordinate = washington;
    alexandriawashingtonlodge.title = @"Alexandria-Washington Lodge No. 22";
    alexandriawashingtonlodge.subtitle = @"Alexandria, VA";
    [self.myMapView addAnnotation:alexandriawashingtonlodge];
```

This list continues for a total of about 310 lodge locations.

Comment: Are you intentionally creating an Annotation object with only `-alloc` but not `-init`?

Comment: Hi Rickay, fist thanks for your time. I am VERY new to coding. I watched a few tutorial via google / youtube and I have been building it based off the information from that an a few books that I have picked up. I'm really not sure of the difference but I will google it. But in short to answer your question. No I did not intentionally create the annotation object with only -alloc

Comment: At this point, you never want to create an object with just `-alloc`. Use `-alloc` `-init` instead. This both allocates the memory for the object and initializes it, as opposed to just allocating the memory for it.

Comment: Rickay, Looking at my code. I Think I did this... each lodge has -alloc and -init in the code...

Comment: Do you see any pattern to what lodges appear and which don't?

Comment: Let me see if it stops in order or not. Ill get back with you in about 15-20 mins. Good question! I did not think about that.

Comment: Its random! I have them listed in order A-Z by city.. I have some from the A's some from the R's some from C's and D's..

Comment: @Apps this isn't directly related to your question but you may want to consider having a data source and using a for loop instead of hand coding 310 separate locations. I can guarantee it will make your code easier to maintain.

Comment: Thanks stephenmuss, I'll look into that. Any recommendations for the data source? do you mean like a plist? because thats a pain to create lol.

Comment: You could use a plist and there are plenty of tools which will make it less a pain to create. However, you could also investigate core data. Whatever you choose, I'm sure you will find it less a pain to maintain than directly in code.

Comment: How many of the 310 locations are you using CLGeocoder with?  Geocoding too many locations at once may fail for various reasons.  If these locations are static, pre-geocode them once (either manually or in a timed loop) and store the coordinates with the locations (and don't geocode every time at run-time).  Also, `[Annotation alloc];` should be `[[Annotation alloc] init];`.

Comment: All 310 are using CLgeocoder. Also what do you mean by pre-geocode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that some of my annotations are not showing up is because I'm calling on CLGeocoder to many times. Here is how I fixed the issue.

`//Columbia Lodge No. 285
    CLLocationCoordinate2D columbia;
    columbia.latitude = 38.895746;
    columbia.longitude = -77.106511;
    Annotation *columbialodge = [[Annotation alloc] init];
    columbialodge.coordinate = columbia;
    columbialodge.title = @"Columbia Lodge No. 285";
    columbialodge.subtitle = @"Arlington, VA";
    [self.myMapView addAnnotation:columbialodge];`

I'v converted all my of address to Lat long. Which has cut down on memory usage as well.

As much as I enjoyed just putting in the address it looks like  CLGeocoder is just taking up to many resources.

Answer (score 1):

Use like this,

```
NSString *abingdon = @"325 W Main Street Abingdon, Virginia 24210";
CLGeocoder *abingdongeo = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[abingdongeo geocodeAddressString:abingdon completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0) {
CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:topResult];
MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
point.coordinate = placemark.coordinate;
point.title = @"Abingdon Lodge No. 48";
point.subtitle = @"Abingdon, VA";

// Set your region using placemark (not point)          
MKCoordinateRegion region = self.mapView.region;
region.center = placemark.region.center;
region.span.longitudeDelta /= 8.0;
region.span.latitudeDelta /= 8.0;

// Add point (not placemark) to the mapView                                              
[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
[self.mapView addAnnotation:point];

// Select the PointAnnotation programatically
[self.mapView selectAnnotation:point animated:NO]; }}];
```